# Instalar el pixel de facebook correctamente

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin, facebook, facebook-api

Buen día compas.

Estoy trabajando en un sitio con woocommerce y los compas mkt me solicitan implementar el API del Pixel de Facebook para los eventos.

Los eventos ya los esta registrando el pixel pero aparecen que fueron enviados desde el navegador, me comentan que es indispensable que los eventos estén añadidos por el servidor y en el navegador como lo marcan Ver Contenido, ViewCategory y Buscar. De la imagen del siguiente enlace:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El sitio tiene instalado el plugin de Facebook para wocommerce con el comportamiento predeterminado de los eventos.

¿Que es lo mejor? Dejar el plugin e insertar los eventos complementarios? O Eliminarlo y hacer todos los eventos con código?

En el caso del page view tengo una duda con el cache, y es que al tener cache instalado no lleguen mis solicitudes al pixel porque se esta procesando el cache de la pagina en turno del lado del servidor.

Les agradezco su guía de antemano

Answer (score 0):

lo mejor es hacerlo con el plugin oficial de facebook pixel para woocommerce:  [Click Aqui](https://woocommerce.com/es-es/products/facebook/).

Si encuentras que no te funciona bien, puedes hacerlo en código si te brinda confianza.

Y con relación a tu duda, el caché no reemplaza el trabajo del código del lado servidor.

Éxitos!